# How do i get the CourseWork class using the Java Google Classroom API?

Tags: java, google-api, google-classroom

Sorry if its a stupid question, but I cant find the answer anywhere. I'm new to the google classroom api.

How do I get the CourseWork instance out of a Course instance?

Answer (score 0):

1. Step: Use the method `courses.list` to list all your courses and the `ids` with https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list
2. Step: Use the `id` of the course you are interested in as `courseId` for the method `courses.courseWork.list` to list all the courseWork related to this course: https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list

Comment: Now sorry for asking, but this returns the com.google.api.services.classroom.Classroom.Courses.CourseWork wich has no way of getting any data from it (that i found), so how do i get data from a instance of this class? (ex. Title and Description)

Comment: You can e.g. set the parameter `fields`to `courseWork/title`. Have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork#resource:-coursework) to understand the nesting structure of a Coursework resource. Also, test with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list) feature to see what the response looks like.

Comment: I solved it by creating a new class with all the fields of a coursework since the model is old. So I was able to get titles and description. It ain't the preatyest fix but it does the thing.